# How can I backup/restore Opera browser bookmarks?

Tags: 15.04, browser, opera

I was wondering if someone has successfully backed up and restored Opera bookmarks on Ubuntu?
I dont see any options to do so and I cant find any useful information on the internet either.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

**One method** is to use an extension for exporting the bookmarks, such as this one (sidebar extension): https://addons.opera.com/extensions/details/v7-bookmarks/. It will create an HTML file which should work with other browsers too.
Then you can import bookmarks from here: *opera://settings/importData* (Select "From: Bookmarks HTML file").

**Another method** is to do it manually, by going to ~/.config/opera, and copy the file "Bookmarks", and later restore it.

Answer (score 0):

Today Opera has a sync feature which does an excellent job of managing bookmarks across all devices/platforms - their developer release is my browse of choice

http://www.opera.com/developer

Opera has really upped their game lately